# Problems accessing Connect function value in another Component in a React-Redux App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've set up Redux in my React app, however I don't get any data passed when I use `this.props` to access the data in another component in a separate file. My action is being executed and it passes the data I want.
This is my `actions.js`:

```
export const ADD_CART = 'ADD_CART';

export function addCart(item){
    return {
        type: ADD_CART,
        payload: item
    }
};
```

My `reducer.js` is:

```
import {ADD_CART} from './actions';

export default Reducer;

function Reducer(state, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_CART:
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: action.payload
            } 
    };
}
```

My action creator contains `cart`, which is what I want to pass to the component:

```
...
class WebShop extends Component {
    ...

    handleClick() {
        let cart = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:this.state.value};
        this.props.onCartAdd(cart);
    } 

   ...


    render() {
        return (
            ..
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onCartAdd: (cart) => {
            dispatch(addCart(cart));
        },
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
      cartItem: state.reducer,
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(WebShop);
```

When I try to access `cart` in another file and component like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default class Cart extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.cart);
        return(
            <div className= "Webcart" id="Webcart"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my `store.js`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import  reducer  from './reducers';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';


var initialState = {
  cart:"medium",
  data: [],
  url: "/api/comments",
  pollInterval: 2000
}

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    createLogger(),
    thunkMiddleware
  )
);
export default store;
```

My `Provider` is in my `app.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

import App from 'views/App';
import Home from 'views/Home';
import About from 'views/About';
import Cart from 'views/webcart';


console.log(store);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={ hashHistory }>
            <Route path='/' component={ App }>
                <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
                <Route path='about' component={ About } />
                <Route path='Cart' component={ Cart } />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,    
    document.getElementById('app') // eslint-disable-line
);
```

After updating my code to use `mapStateToProps` now I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Reducer' of undefined`. Why I'm I getting this if Reducer should be accessed by the API?

Comment: Can you show us how and where you use `Cart`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the whole code.

Comment: Updated @AndrewLi

Comment: @DanielOMensah Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I saw your pastebin and your comments and I feel like you are so close especially with @Faaiz answer (so read this answer in line with @Faaiz's store, initialState and reducer response). So lets roll it back:

Say you have two components (WebShop and Cart); and you want to share a global state (cart) with these components. Either of these ways works:

1. Nested Components of a "Connected Component" - say `<Cart />` is a child of `<WebShop />` which is connected (via redux connect with mapStateToProps etc.) to the global state. Then within WebShop, you could do something like:

   ```
   import { addCart } from './actions';
   import { connect } from 'react-redux';
   // other imports    
   class WebShop extends Component {
     ...//
     handleClick() {
       const cart = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:this.state.value};
       this.props.onCartAdd(cart);
     } 
     render() {
       return (
         ...//
         <Cart cart={this.props.cart} />
       )
     }
   }
   // for completeness I brought the mapStateToProps
   function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return { cart: state.cart };
   }

   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return {
       onCartAdd: (item) => {
         dispatch(addCart(item));
       }
     }
   }
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WebShop);
   ```

and in your cart.js file, you could do:

```
    class Cart extends Component {
      ...//
      render() {
        console.log("cart", this.props.cart)
        return (
          ...//
        )
      }
    }
```

2. Two separately "Connected Component"s - which means connect both components (via redux connect with mapStateToProps etc.) to the global state. So both your cart and webshop will be similar in this respect like so:

   ```
   class WebShop extends Component {
     ...//
     render() {
       console.log("cart", this.props.cart)
       return (
         ...// Other stuffs 
       )
     }
   }
   // for completeness I brought the mapStateToProps, you should include the mapDispatchToProps
   function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return { cart: state.cart };
   }
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WebShop);
   ```

and cart.js file would look like so:

```
    class Cart extends Component {
      ...//
      render() {
        console.log("cart", this.props.cart)
        return (
          ...//
        )
      }
    }
    // for completeness I brought the mapStateToProps, you should include the mapDispatchToProps
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return { cart: state.cart };
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

**NOTE**
I would rather set up your `addCart` action to be `addItemToCart` and your global state `cart` will now be an array of items. Your reducer.js would look similar to:

```
const initialState = { 
  cart: [],
  data: [],
  url: "/api/comments",
  pollInterval: 2000
};

function Reducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case ADD_CART:
      return {
          ...state,
          cart: state.cart.push(action.payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  };
}
```

and your `handleClick()` would look like

```
handleClick() {
  const item = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:this.state.value};
  this.props.onCartAdd(item);
}
```

But feel free to go with your use case, my opinion may be totally off.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How should I set up my `handleClick()` function if it can't be `this.props.onCartAdd(cart);` ?

Comment: @feners, your `handleClick()` should work fine with `this.props.onCartAdd(cart)` as long as you included your `mapDispatchToProps` (now included in the answer)

Comment: But I get an error that it is not defined since you are not using `mapDispatchToProps` and that's where `onCartAdd` is defined ...

Comment: oh @feners, I didn't want to reinvent Faaiz's answer, that was why I said read this answer in line with that. But see my updates, hope that clarifies things.

Comment: I'm trying your second suggestion and it seems to almost work. However it's giving me this error `Warning: ReactComponent(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define 'render'.` when I try to access the `Cart` component even though I have defined render..is it rendering an undefined?

Comment: I awarded the answer to you because it has gotten me the farthest, I know I'm close to getting it..if you can keep assisting me with this it would be awesome!

Comment: @feners, definitely willing to help. I do think we should continue off here though, probably via direct message. Message me with where you are at, if that's ok.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this should trigger to open in the chat to continue.. let's continue there, thanks!

Comment: Hey! If you can still help me out with this, I could really use the help.

Comment: Hey, sure can. Just don't want to pollute here. I sent you a chat invite. I'm going to send it again.

Answer (score 1):

To access data you need to pass the state to the connect api. You only passed in the dispatch action to the props

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    SomeDataProperty: state.Reducer
  }
}
```

Also your mapDispatchToProps is in the return statement of your component, it is better practice to put that function in a different file (the container)  and then point that container with the connected props to the WebShop component if you are trying to make WebShop pass props to the Cart component.

Example:

WebshopContainer.jsx  (container component, which will pass the props to the component)

```
import WebShop from './WebShop';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    SomeDataProperty: state.Reducer // prop Reducer was taken from your reducer.js because it was passed into here from the connect API
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return {
        onCartAdd: (cart) => {
            dispatch(addCart(cart));
        },
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)( WebShop ); // pass in the component here
```

component file that has component WebShop and you want to pass props to component   so that component can access the props:

```
class WebShop extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cartData: {}
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    const waitForProps = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.props.Reducer.hasOwnProperty('some prop you gave it')) {
        clearInterval(waitForProps);
        this.setState({ cartData: this.props.Reducer['some data property you used'] });
      }
    });
  }
  handleClick() {
      let cart = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:this.state.value};
      this.props.onCartAdd(cart);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Cart cart={ this.state.cartData }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the `mapStateToProps` function to my code, but I can't figure out how it can pass `cart`..

Comment: Applying your method to my code gives me this error `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onCartAdd is not a function`

Comment: Did you connect the container to your WebShop component? Also the file that contains the WebShop component needs to import the 'container' file

Comment: How should I import the container file in the WebShop file? `import ?? from "./WebshopContainer"`?

Comment: Import the container from the parent component. Whichever component is rendering WebShop right now is currently rendering just the component. If you put the container in a different file (recommended best practice) then you need to make the parent component render that container file and your WebShop component will still get rendered normally because its being imported from the container

Comment: You got me a bit confused..what is the parent component you are referring to? My root component?

Comment: I set it up exactly how you have it in your example, with the container in a different file..I imported Webshop to my container file,  but how would I import the container file if it only has two functions in them and the connect?

Comment: I've been working with it and now I'm getting a flood of errors `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined` what value should `if (this.props.Reducer.hasOwnProperty('cart'))` take if it's not `cart`?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a couple of issues here:

1. You are not importing the action when you create your connected component

   ```
   import { addCart } from './actions'
   // ... rest of your code: component, mapStateToProps, etc.
   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return {
       onCartAdd: (cart) => {
         dispatch(addCart(cart));
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Your reducer MUST return a default state

   ```
   function Reducer(state = {}, action){
     switch(action.type){
       case ADD_CART:
         return {
             ...state,
             cart: action.payload
         }

       default: 
          return state          

     }
   }
   ```

EDIT

Another bug I found. You are returning the name of the reducer only. Should you not also return `cart`?

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    cart: state.reducer.cart
  }
}
```

Comment: I was importing my action, did not paste it here sorry about that. However, even adding the return state, I get the same error..

Comment: Ok, could you paste all your code? Also where you create your store and you render the `Provider` component?

Comment: Can you share also the code of `reducers` module? I noticed you `import reducer from './reducers' but I don't see that code in your question. It might be that the problem

Comment: Ah! This might be it.. i should be importing `import Reducer from './reducers'` ... I have to check this out.. thanks for noticing this..

Answer (score 1):

Move your initial state from the `store.js` to your `reducer.js` and pass it to the reducer function to have the state defaulted to, like this

```
const initialState = { 
  cart: {}, // change this to object to hold that cart your're 
           //passing or an array to hold multiple cart, in which 
           // case you will need to handle the return of your
           // state differently in your reducer
  data: [],
  url: "/api/comments",
  pollInterval: 2000
};

function Reducer(state = initialState, action){
switch(action.type){
    case ADD_CART:
        return {
            ...state,
            cart: action.payload
        } 
    };
    default:
        return state;
}
```

This will make sure you have no undefined states and an action not registered with the `reducer` returns the state of the store.

Your action dispatches a payload `item` which gets set as `state.cart` of the store, not the `state.reducer`.

so in your `WebShop component` change your `mapStateToProps`

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
      cartItem: state.cart.item // to access your item inside your cart
   }
}
```

And to access this `cart` in another component you either need to pass it to the props of that component like this for stateless components 
    const cartItem = this.state.cartItem // get this from either the state or props or from the `mapDispatchToProps` in `connect` like you're doing in the `webshop component`

```
<Component cart={cartItem} />
```

as cartItem is now in your state, you should be able to do something like this.

```
class OtherComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       {/* render some other components */}
       <Component cartItem={this.props.cartItem}
     </div>
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { cartItem: state.cart.item };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(OtherComponent);
```

Hope this clarifies your issue.

Comment: How should I import `cartItem` in my other file? I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: cartItem is not defined` using `<Component cart={cartItem} />`.

Comment: In which component are you rendering the `<Component />` ?

Comment: @feners I've edited my post and included a way to access state of the store.

Comment: I'm not sure if I applied this correctly but I'm getting `Warning: ReactComponent(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define 'render'.`. This is how I'm trying to `cart` https://pastebin.com/zaAqgRhg

Comment: added `const cartItem = this.state.cartItem;` to my `Cart` component render and now I get `const cartItem = this.state.cartItem;`.

Comment: @feners has this solved your issue? if not, where are you at with it?

Comment: My last comment shows where I'm still stuck at..the comment before that one has the pastebin for what I was last trying inside the component I want to use get the `cart`. @flash